# Adding all users in my Azure AD to a power platform environment

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-365, power-platform

I have inherited a number of power platform environments.
They all appear to have all users from AD as users, but with no security roles assigned.
(see image 1 below)

I thought an AD security group might have been assigned to the environment but it has not (see image 2).

Any new environments I create only have users I specifically assign, or if I assign an AD Security group.

Can anyone advise how all the users from AD are appearing as users in this Environment?

[image: All ad users are users for an environment]

[image: No security group from AD Assigned]

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is the opposite of the D365 behavior. In case there is NO security group added, all the AD users will be by default added to the environment with no security roles.

Hence it is always advisable to have

1. Environment level security group to manage users
2. This SG should be different for different environments eg:Pre-Prod SG and
   PROD SG should be separated, to eliminate any non-prod users
3. Team level SG ( to manage security roles assignment on single shot)

Comment: this does not match with the behavior i am seeing either. I have other environments where no security group is added and the only users they have are users that i explicitly add.